# tengo este error illegal start of type / illegal start of expression, cómo lo resuelvo?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache, fetch, class

Tengo este error justo en la línea de @JoinTable y no estaría encontrando la solución. No puedo correr el código en maven porque el error afecta a todo mi proyecto. No entiendo dónde se encuentra específicamente el error que me salta. Si alguien fuera tan amable de explicarme qué hacer. Desde ya muchísimas gracias.

```
public class Usuario {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@NotNull
private String nombre;
@NotNull
@Column (unique = true)
private String nombreUsuario;
@NotNull
private String email;
@NotNull
private String password;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id"));
private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();
.
.
.
//Continua código

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes definir las anotaciones sin terminar con ";" ya que esto provocará que no las reconozca como tal, en este caso la anotación es:

```
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id"))
```

por lo tanto define de esta forma la variable `roles`

```
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id"))
private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();
```